# Issue streaming ffmpeg webcam feed with ffserver

Tags: debian, ffmpeg, video-streaming, ffserver

**see comments for updates on research on issue**

I'm fiddling with ffmpeg, ffserver a webcam and Debian Wheezy in order to stream video content. I am able to watch my webcam's footage via mplayer, using:

```
mplayer -fps 30 -tv driver=v4l2:width=640:height=480:device=/dev/video0 tv://
```

Also I am able to start the ffserver, using the default ffserver.conf, obtained from here:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html

```
ffserver -d -f /etc/ffserver.conf
```

I understand that I need to have ffmpeg convert the webcam's input into a usable
format for the feed I have defined in ffserver.conf. In order to do so I use:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 /tmp/feed1.ffm
```

Starting this the system asks whether or not to overwrite the existing file, I answer Y
and the system starts streaming to that file.

However, clicking on the relevant stream (mpg) on localhost:8090/stat.html times out without showing any content, also ffserver does not display errors - yet started in -d debug mode.

I suspect I miss the essential final part in connecting the feed provided by ffmpeg with the streaming capability of ffserver.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Them excellent folks at #ffmpeg on freenode have helped me to get closer to resolving this. First thing: ffmpeg -f ... must not point to the local file but to http://IP:port/feed1.ffm, also they advised to compile ffmpeg from scratch - which I did: new ffmpeg command I'm working with:  ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0  -b:a 32k -c:a libmp3lame http://127.0.0.1:8090/feed1.ffm - new error message: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height. Any thoughts, anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having followed the steps I have learned on #ffmpeg I eventually got this going - bottom line of things to do:

- build ffmpeg and related tools from source (http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)
- use webm instead of mpeg format

Very helpful read: https://www.virag.si/2012/11/streaming-live-webm-video-with-ffmpeg/

After having achieved this I found a fairly interesting project on this topic, Zoneminder (http://www.zoneminder.com) - straight forward, easy to use - did the trick for my use case like a charm. Great stuff.